# How can I select between multiple different variants of an import statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, import, three.js, preprocessor

If javascript had a 'C like' preprocessor, what I want to do would look like this...

```
#define LOCAL
#if LOCAL
import * as THREE from '../three.js'
import { GUI } from '../three.js/examples/jsm/libs/dat.gui.module'
import { TWEEN } from '../three.js/examples/jsm/libs/lil-gui.module.min.js'
import * as BufferGeometryUtils from '../three.js/examples/jsm/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.js'
#elif
// Use for website
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.133.1/build/three.module.js'
import { GUI } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.138.1/examples/jsm/libs/lil-gui.module.min.js'
import { TWEEN } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.133.1/examples/jsm/libs/tween.module.min'
import * as BufferGeometryUtils from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.133.1/examples/jsm/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.js'
#endif
```

Basically, I want to minimize the amount of editing that I need to do across all of my project's files when I switch from a locally hosted webserver to my website's webserver.